# ¿Error de conversión SQL SERVER "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to bit" en una consulta?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

La siguiente consulta me muestra un

> error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SI EXISTE' to data type bit.

no se como resolverlo, la columna4 es de tipo BIT pero a veces quiero obtener el tipo bit y a veces quiero obtener un texto para que tenga mas significado para el usuario, eso lo controlo con una variable que se llama @TextoOrBit.

De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo y si me pueden orientar a como obtener el resultado deseado.

```
DECLARE 
   @TextoOrBit BIT

SET @TextoOrBit = 0;

 SELECT 
   COLUMNA1,
   COLUMNA2,
   COLUMNA3,
   CASE @TextoOrBit 
      WHEN 1 THEN 
          CASE COLUMNA4 WHEN 1 THEN 'SI EXISTE' ELSE 'NO EXISTE' END
      ELSE 
          CASE COLUMNA4 WHEN 1 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END
   END AS  COLUMNA4_custom
 FROM
   TABLA_DATOS
```

Comment: COLUMNA4 es varchar o bit? por que en tu query dice que quieres guardar un bit dentro de un varchar

Comment: si quieres que tenga significado para el usuario, no deberias resolverlo en el procedure, que este revuelva el valor de COLUMNA4 tenga, despues en codigo c# es donde evaluas el contenido y tomas la desicion como mostrar al usuario el valor. Pero remarco no hagas eso en el procedure

Comment: @RICARDO la columna es de tipo BIT, realmente cuando obtengo el bit no hay problema se ejecuta y obtiene el resultado pero cuando quiero obtener el texto me marca el error de conversión.

Comment: Te marca el error porque estas queriendo devolver un varchar donde deberias poner un bit, si en la estructura de tu tabla, tu campo COLUMNA4 es bit, solo va a aceptar bit, y tu estas queriendo mostrar 'SI EXISTE' o 'NO EXISTE'

Comment: @LeandroTuttini pense que funcionaria desde la consulta. Yo tengo una clase en mi aplicación que recibe todos los campos de la consulta. y es guardada en un list<>. y debido a que la consulta es llamada en dos funciones distintas necesitaba en una el valor del bit y en otra un texto.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de la clase que usas en el List<> ?

Comment: ¿No te sirve retornar los 2 valores en el `SELECT` y luego en tu programa tomar la columna que corresponda según el tipo de dato? Quiero decir, que en tu `SELECT` obtengas junto a las otras columnas, también `COLUMNA4` y `COLUMNA4_custom`, de modo que en esta última siempre obtengas el `varchar`. Luego en tu programa, si necesita el `BIT`, se remite a `COLUMNA4`; si necesita el texto descriptivo, se remite a `COLUMNA4_custom`.... Es una pregunta.
*Editado* Acabo de ver que Leandro te dijo algo similar ya en su comentario. Lo que te decimos son alternativas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si defines una clase para la `List<>`, puedes ejecutar una sola vez la consulta y tener propiedades

```
public class Class1{

   //otras propiedades      

   public bool COLUMNA4 {get;set;}

   public string COLUMNA4Text
   {
      get { return this.COLUMNA4 ? "SI EXISTE" : "NO EXISTE"; }
   }
}
```

desde la consulta obtienes el valor `bit` del campo que por supuesto en c# es un bool, pero despues para el texto solo expones una propiedad `readonly` que permite obtener el texto que mostraras al usuario y queda todo encapsulado en la clase